# How to use google charts to plot CSV data file?

Tags: javascript, csv, charts, google-visualization

I’m trying to plot a candlestick chart data from a csv file using google charts; I have failed miserably... I read all the posts, some are quite old and google chart methods/js has since been updated anyway. The posts seem to reference an old js (jquery.csv.min.js) which has also been deprecated. Can you point me to a ‘current’ working example which plots the data from a csv file on the same web server? I also tried following the instructions on the google charts site (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/queries#reading-csv-files) but with no success... the debugger shows the data being loaded but it seems the callback isn’t triggered... a complete working example would help me a lot.

Comment: What have you tried so far  (code) ? There are updated articles on candlestick charts but seems your issue is to pull data from CSV, please check this link

As per googlechart site (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/queries-stealth)

If you want to build a chart out of CSV (comma-separated values) data, you have two choices:

1 - Convert the data into the Google Charts datatable format
2 - Place the CSV file on the web server serving the chart, and query it using the technique on this page.

Comment: Hi Allende, yes... that I have tried (the two methods have been described in the link in my question)... hosting the csv on the web server and querying it doesn’t work for some reason... the only script(s) that have worked used jquery-csv ... and even that I’ve struggled to get working with candlestick data... I literally tried all codes I could google!

Comment: will you please share a sample of the data?

Comment: Here’s the link to a sample (http://csv.pub/wakanda/sample.csv) ... it has a head that looks like this: DateTime,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume

Answer (score 0):

As a simple workaround, you could upload you csv file to Google Drive and convert it to a Google Spreadsheet. Then, all you have to do is to generate the public link (by sharing it), copy the spreadsheet ID and paste it into the query parameter:

```
var query = new google.visualization.Query(
    "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/1/d/" +
    "<paste the spreadsheet ID here>" + 
    "/gviz/tq?sheet=1&headers=1"
  );
```

If you'd rather keep your data private, take a look on the following website regarding OAuth authorization: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets#Authorization

As a bonus, Google Spreadsheets do not count against your storage limit on Google Drive.

Comment: Hi Bruno, I have a script that produces/updates the csv every x mins... If it was a one-off csv then yes, that would be a nice idea... but unfortunately this won’t work on a continuously updating csv...